# How to find the accurate tile rect of a MKMapPoint?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mapkit

**Is this the right way to find the MapTile rect from a point ?**

I have find the following code from other resources but it seems, it is not accurate as needed.

// Convert latitude and longitude to pixel values at zoom level 20

```
#define MERCATOR_OFFSET 268435456 /* (total pixels at zoom level 20) / 2 */

#define MERCATOR_RADIUS 85445659.44705395 /* MERCATOR_OFFSET / pi */

x = round(MERCATOR_OFFSET + MERCATOR_RADIUS * longitude * M_PI / 180.0);

y = round(MERCATOR_OFFSET - MERCATOR_RADIUS * logf((1 + sinf(latitude * M_PI / 180.0)) / (1 -
sinf(latitude * M_PI / 180.0))) / 2.0);
```

Expected at the time of `drawMapRect` requested, `MKMapRect` origin should be same as point(x,y).

Any suggestion appreciated...

Comment: I dont see you getting any kind of rect.

Comment: Generally, you should be using the [functions that Map Kit provides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008209) to do any calculations.  If you post your drawMapRect, it might be easier to understand what you need.

Comment: @Pradeep, can you share an example of such inaccuracy you get (points, NSLogs...) ? How exactly do you know that it is really an inaccuracy? I am doing some investigations on a similar question and want to know what problems did you see with this code.